# SVR Regression with first point same as (x0,y0)

Tags: python, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have data like this:

```
x = np.array([   0.  ,    3.  ,    3.3 ,   10.  ,   18.  ,   43.  ,   80.  ,
           120.  ,  165.  ,  210.  ,  260.  ,  310.  ,  360.  ,  410.  ,
           460.  ,  510.  ,  560.  ,  610.  ,  660.  ,  710.  ,  760.  ,
           809.5 ,  859.  ,  908.5 ,  958.  , 1007.5 , 1057.  , 1106.5 ,
           1156.  , 1205.5 , 1255.  , 1304.5 , 1354.  , 1403.5 , 1453.  ,
           1502.5 , 1552.  , 1601.5 , 1651.  , 1700.5 , 1750.  , 1799.5 ,
           1849.  , 1898.5 , 1948.  , 1997.5 , 2047.  , 2096.5 , 2146.  ,
           2195.5 , 2245.  , 2294.5 , 2344.  , 2393.5 , 2443.  , 2492.5 ,
           2542.  , 2591.5 , 2640.  , 2690.  , 2740.  , 2789.67, 2839.33,
           2891.5 ])
y = array([ 1.45  ,  1.65  ,  5.8   ,  6.8   ,  8.0355,  8.0379,  8.04  ,
           8.0505,  8.175 ,  8.3007,  8.4822,  8.665 ,  8.8476,  9.0302,
           9.528 ,  9.6962,  9.864 , 10.032 , 10.2   , 10.9222, 11.0553,
           11.1355, 11.2228, 11.3068, 11.3897, 11.4704, 11.5493, 11.6265,
           11.702 , 11.7768, 11.8491, 11.9208, 11.9891, 12.0571, 12.1247,
           12.1912, 12.2558, 12.3181, 12.3813, 12.4427, 12.503 , 12.5638,
           12.6226, 12.6807, 12.7384, 12.7956, 12.8524, 12.9093, 12.9663,
           13.0226, 13.0786, 13.1337, 13.1895, 13.2465, 13.3017, 13.3584,
           13.4156, 13.4741, 13.5311, 13.5899, 13.6498, 13.6533, 13.657 ,
           13.6601])
```

and iam do this:

```
svr_res = SVR(kernel='rbf',C=100,gamma=0.5,epsilon=0.1)
X = np.arange(0,np.max(x),10).reshape(-1,1)
Y = svr_res.fit(x,y).predict(X)
```

and the result like this :

[image]

Where the red line is my data. I don't know why iam get result like that (blue line is the issue at my result). My goal is can make curve smooth with a nice result (RMS was low) and start from point (x(0),y(0))

Comment: the blue or red line is causing the issue?

Comment: @ombk the blue one is the issue